# Magento 1.9 reindex showing timeout

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When i try to re-index Magento indexes, I got connection time out error.

I am not able to re-index.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-index done by 2 ways like below :

**1). Using Admin Side :**

Go to Admin > System > and find "Index Management" option and do reindex.

**2). Using Command-line :**

Go to magento root and php shell/indexer.php -reindexall.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you unable to reindexing from admin panel, you can reindex through command line.

- Login in putty
- reach the magento root path
- run the below command

  php shell/indexer.php --reindex all

you can re-index the data individually:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
php shell/indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```